# Avoid inserting data into a table using Trigger and raise_application_error, but store the data into a Log table

Tags: oracle, logging, plsql, triggers, insert

I need to check if the product sale has expired or not, comparing it's date to the actual date of the computer. If the product expired then I can't insert the product data into the Order Table, but i need to insert them into a Log Table.
I can avoid inserting into the Order Table using `raise_application_error (-20001,'This product is not for sale anymore');`. But when i use raise_application_error it seems that raise_application_error rollback also the command `INSERT INTO LogTable ...`, which is inside the trigger. Is there a better way to solve this problem not using raise_application_error?
Observation: I need to use Trigger and can't use INSTEAD-OF

```
create or replace TRIGGER Insercao_DetalhesPedido
    AFTER INSERT ON DetalhesPedido
    REFERENCING new AS novo_DP
    FOR EACH ROW

  DECLARE
    dataPedido Pedido.DTPedido%TYPE;
    dataVenda Produto.DTFimVenda%TYPE;
    dtVenda_Expirou EXCEPTION;

  BEGIN
    -- get the date from the order(it is a SYSDATE)
    SELECT DTPedido INTO dataPedido
    FROM Pedido 
    WHERE Pedido.codigo = :novo_DP.codigoPedido;

    -- get the date from the product(when it will expire)
    SELECT DTFimVenda INTO dataVenda
    FROM Produto
    WHERE Produto.codigo = :novo_DP.codigoProduto;

    --has the product expired?
    IF dataVenda < dataPedido THEN 
    -- Insert INTO the log table saying that this product have expired
      INSERT INTO Log
      VALUES(:novo_DP.codigoPedido, :novo_DP.codigoProduto, cast(SYSDATE as timestamp), dataPedido, 
             'Insercao Falha. DTVenda('||dataVenda||') < DataPedido('||dataPedido||')');
      RAISE dtVenda_Expirou;
    ELSE
      -- Insert INTO the log table saying that the product was succesfully inserted
       INSERT INTO Log
       VALUES(:novo_DP.codigoPedido, :novo_DP.codigoProduto, cast(SYSDATE as timestamp), dataPedido, 
             'Inserção De Produto em DetalhesPedido com sucesso');
    END IF;  

  EXCEPTION
  -- Product expired
  WHEN dtVenda_Expirou THEN
      raise_application_error (-20001,'A DATA DE VENDA DO PRODUTO EXPIROU');
  -- Order number not found
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001,'NUMERO DO PEDIDO NÃO EXISTE');

END Insercao_DetalhesPedido;
```

I put some comments in English as my code is in portuguese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Autonomous Pragma` to log your data regardless the exception. Basically, you create a procedure to insert into the log table. The procedure could have the syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE auto_log(your parameters) is
....
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;   --This statement makes the procedure autonomous
BEGIN
--your insert into log statement
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

And your trigger will be something like:

```
....
--has the product expired?
IF dataVenda < dataPedido THEN 
-- Insert INTO the log table saying that this product have expired
   auto_log(your parameters)  --- call the procedure
   RAISE dtVenda_Expirou;
ELSE
  -- Insert INTO the log table saying that the product was succesfully inserted
  auto_log(your parameters)  --- call the procedure
END IF;  

EXCEPTION
-- Product expired
WHEN dtVenda_Expirou THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001,'A DATA DE VENDA DO PRODUTO EXPIROU');
-- Order number not found
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  raise_application_error (-20001,'NUMERO DO PEDIDO NÃO EXISTE');

END Insercao_DetalhesPedido;
```

See [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_autonomous_transaction.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Autonomous Pragma` here. It will ensure that parent transaction doesn't rollback child transaction. 
This is a standard practice for logging in sql and pl/sql.

See an example here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0560__Trigger/Autonomoustriggers.htm

EDIT:

My suggestion would be to create a separate pl/sql proc using Autonomous pragma for inserting in log table and call this proc wherever required. This would ensure that log statements are not rolled back.